# Multiple Labels from attribute column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, fields-attributes, word-cloud

I was wondering if there is a way to have multiple labels from a joined attribute table in QGIS. I have two tables, a polygon table, and a table with words (codes). The codes table can be joined by a foreign key (geoid) with the codes table. I would like to simulate a word cloud (see image below) in QGIS doing the following (if it is possible):

1) Set a label from a joined table
2) Have many labels shown, and sized according to their frequency in the table

[image: Simulated word cloud]

Simulated word cloud

[image: Codes table]

Codes table with words to display and frequency of words.

Any thoughts or insight is welcomed.

Comment: I think there is no "easy" solution for this without coding (which I can't in QGIS, I chose the R way to mass pre-preprocess data for QGIS). The main problem here is, that you have to many-to-one relation here, so multiple informations for the same geometry. A first theoretical workflow: Create centroids for your polygons. Add xy-columns with coordinates via field calculator. Now join the centroids table to the data table. Export this table as csv and reimport it as text-delimited layer with your xy-columns. Now you have as many points as you have data.

Comment: For the labeling then, use the Easy Custom Labeling plugin to add columns for data-driven representation of your labels, copy/recalculate your size values to the LblSize column. Now you have all advanced possibilities to influence to outcome (move labels, change colors for all tags via field calculator etc.)

Comment: Thanks Bernad V. but I was hoping for a more automated way, and coding is an option, just not sure if the underlaying API and support this.